# Login Process (Possibly in MySQL/PHP)

Tags: mysql

I have a problem which I cannot seem to be able to resolve: I'm creating a login process for an application; anytime a user attempts to login and fails, an attempt record is inserted/updated up to 5 attempts. After the 5th attempt, the account is locked. 
I have 2 tables for that process, the 'user' table where the user information is kept, and the 'attempts' table. 
First, I don't want to use a session or cookie variable for the counting of attempts (cookies can be deleted, and session variables can become too much, since it's a high traffic site); I plan to use an update statement to increase the number by 1. 
Here's where the confusion starts: 
 
First, I'm not sure if I should update the row in the attempt table, or just insert a new row for every attempt (my preference is to insert on the first attempt, and to update the row on the remaining 4 attempts). 
Second, I need a way to indicate that the attempt being made today is completely different from the one yesterday. For example, if a user attempted to log in yesterday, and succeeded after the third attempt, and then today, he attempted to login again, I don't want the attempt to increment yesterday's attempt. So, in a way, after every successful login, I need a way to ensure that any attempt after a successful login starts a new login process by itself. 
I'm not sure if my question is clear. Please, ask for more clarification if needed. 
I've racked my brain for 2 days without a solution to this process. 


Thanks 


P.S: I'm using stored procedure for most of the processing to eliminate the traveling back and forth for the processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than have a separate table for login attempts, simply add a counter as a new integer column on the user table.  Each time a failed attempt is made, increment that column for that record.  Each time a successful login is made, reset that column to 0 for that record.

If you need to keep a running audit of all attempts, that's a separate concern.  Auditing isn't part of the login process.  For that concern you'd write failed attempts to some kind of audit log.  This log can be a table in the database, but shouldn't be linked to the transactional tables in any way.  And it can be a general logging system for all kind of application events, not just for failed logins.  (Again, another concern entirely.)

Comment: Thank you very much; it sure seems extremely simple with your explanation.